# Where to operate on data?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My controller calls a repository which gets data from a model, this is then returned up the chain to the controller, which outputs the data in a view.

Where should I operate on this data? For example, perhaps I wish to add a random object to the data:

```
//Controller
$data = $this->repository->getAllRows();
```

Where should this go? in the controller? in the eloquent repository?

```
$data->splice(0, 5, [$myNewObject]);
```

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't do it in either.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you are doing it for. If its directly related to data, you can place it in model, or its directly related to logic, keep it on controller.
Like you can keep it on model if you need like:

```
//on model
function getRecentRows()
{
    $data = .....
    return $data->splice(0, 5, [$myNewObject]);
}
```

You will keep this on controller if

```
//on controller
$data = $this->repository->getAllRows();
$data->splice(0, 5, [$myNewObject]);
$datas->each(function($item){
    $item->is_featured = true;
});
//return view with data
```

This might not be the exact answer. You have to provide exact case here.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, but generally I like to keep my models clean without any logic.

Now if that is a single action, just do it in the controller.

If it's a common task and you want to share it along other controllers, you have two options:

- Creating a class so you can use that functionality sometimes inside
  your controllers
- Creating a controller with your operating data functions and extending all of your controllers from it.

I usually adopt this last one, specially when creating API's where I want to create filters to hide some data.

### EDIT

This is a screenshot with a structure that I used for my last project named Paka:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. If I was to opt for the first one - create a class, where would I put this in the laravel framework?

Comment: Usually I create a folder inside the app folder with the name of the project, then it depends, if it's a small project I just put the classes inside that folder, if it's a big project or if it has many classes I create more folders for each type. I have updated my answer with a structure that I have used on my last project.